# Finish a wall with uneven stud surfaces

Tags: bathroom, drywall, walls, studs

I'm remodeling my bathroom.  It was originally plaster so the stud work wasn't exactly spot on.

I installed a new tub and plan on tiling so I had to get the walls squared.  I married 2x4's next to the existing studs and the picture shows the difference.

The new stud behind the behind the concrete board is the new surface level.  The stud next to it is loose fit to highlight the difference to the rest of the wall to the right.

The new wall surface is almost 2in forward at the top and is almost flush at the bottom.

I have no idea how to finish the wall here.  Do I need to marry more squaring studs and shims all the way across the wall?  Is that going to make the window frame there look goofy set in new wall surface?

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were my bathroom I would finish the wall with framing the way you have started. I perhaps would rip the 2X so it is tapered so I would not use so much wood. After that is done and drywall is up I would remove the 1/4 round at the window jamb and replace it with a jamb extension that would meet the face of the new wall. I would also "tweak" the dimensions of the jamb extensions so the taper is not as drastic and let the differences form the wall face get hidden by the trim.

In my opinion, it is much less noticeable to put the difference in the tweaked window jamb than have it where it is now.